# How to get table row index within an alert called by pressing the row

Tags: ios, tableview, uialertview

I have a table view. When a user selects a row, I would like to display a standard "Are you sure?" sort of dialog. But if they are sure some info about what to do is tied to the row they selected. How can I get access to that?

Here's what I have so far.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SitePeople *sitePersonAtIndex = [self.sitePeoples objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIAlertView *alert;
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure?" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This will send an email to %@", sitePersonAtIndex.SitePerson] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Send", nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    self.alertShowing = NO;
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        //cancelled, do nothing
    } else {
        //SitePeople *sitePersonAtIndex = [self.sitePeoples objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        SitePeople *sitePersonAtIndex = [self.sitePeoples objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *email = [defaults stringForKey:@"email"];
        NSString *password = [defaults stringForKey:@"password"];
        [self sendEmail:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://service.pharmatech.com/Share/emailstudy/%@/%@/%@/%@", email, password, self.study.ProjectID, sitePersonAtIndex.SitePeopleID]];
        UIAlertView *alert;
        if (self.alertShowing == NO)
        {
            if ([self.sendEmailResult.WasSuccessful isEqual: @"true"]) {
                alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:self.sendEmailResult.Message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            } else {
                alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:self.sendEmailResult.Message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            }
            [alert show];
        }
    }
}
```

Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the current result you are getting from your attempt? Can you clarify in what way does it not work right now?

Comment: If you use the code I have up there it gives you an out of bounds error. The first line of the else statement in didDismissWithButtonIndex says the max is 3. So I think I'm somehow using the alertview button indexes when I am trying to use tablerow indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need to keep track of the specific row of the table brought up your UIAlertView.

There are a few ways to solve this.

One way might be to simply use your UIAlertView's "`tag`" property to temporarily store the row number.

So, in your "`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`" method, do this after creating your alert:

```
alert.tag = indexPath.row;
```

And in your "`didDismissWithButtonIndex`" delegate method, you can pick up the row from the tag via:

```
NSInteger rowOfTable = alertView.tag;
SitePeople *sitePersonAtIndex = [self.sitePeoples objectAtIndex:rowOfTable];
```

Another way might be @LuisCien's... and +1 to him!

Comment: I'm using the alert.tag method. I was hoping for something a little slicker, but I guess the tag isn't too bad. @LuisCien's would work, too, but this way I don't need to create another variable.

Answer (score 2):

You could have an instance variable that saves the index path (as a way of remembering it) when the user selects a cell, then, when the alert view is dismissed you can use that instance variable to retrieve the information that you need.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.myIndexPath = indexPath; // remember the index path that was selected
    SitePeople *sitePersonAtIndex = [self.sitePeoples objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIAlertView *alert;
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure?" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This will send an email to %@", sitePersonAtIndex.SitePerson] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Send", nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Hope this helps!